# Android app ImageView , not able to load jpg image from internet using Glide

Tags: java, android

I went though all the post from 2019-2021 regarding Using Glide to load image from url. But none of them working for me.

I made sure the following:

1. The JPG URL can be accessed using emulator browser.
2. Internet permission added to AndroidManifest.xml
3. Glider dependency added
4. placeholder image can be displayed if URL didn't fetch the image successfully

I put my config and part of codes here in case something were missed out. Some sample of Logcat messages taken. (It is way too much to paste all). Even with Logcat,i cannot understand what went wrong, I am too new on this.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Ui_basics_lesson17"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.ui_basics_lesson17'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ui_basics_lesson17"
    minSdk 19
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0' //added
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0" //added
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1' //added
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1' //added
}
```

**ViewAdapter.java**

```
   @Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position ) {
     holder.txtName.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
     holder.txtEmail.setText(contacts.get(position).getEmail());
   
   Glide.with(contextFromMainActivity)
   .load(contacts.get(position)
   .getImageUrl()).apply(options)
   .into(holder.image);

     //Use Glide (github library) to load image to holder
    Glide.with(contextFromMainActivity).asBitmap().load(contacts.get(position).getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_failsafe_image1)
            .into(holder.image);

    //set on listener here
    holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(contextFromMainActivity, contacts.get(position)
            .getName() + " Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ui_basics_lesson17;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/*RECYCLE VIEW*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//declare RecyclerView attribute
private RecyclerView contactsRecView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //RecycleView selector
    contactsRecView = findViewById(R.id.contactsRecView);

    //Mock contacts instance ArrayList as database
    ArrayList<Contact> mockContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    mockContacts.add(new Contact("Elon Musk","elonmusk@gmail.com","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Elon_Musk_Royal_Society_%28crop2%29.jpg/220px-Elon_Musk_Royal_Society_%28crop2%29.jpg"));
    mockContacts.add(new Contact("Jack Ma","jackma@gmail.com","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Enabling_eCommerce-_Small_Enterprises%2C_Global_Players_%2839008130265%29_%28cropped%29.jpg/220px-Enabling_eCommerce-_Small_Enterprises%2C_Global_Players_%2839008130265%29_%28cropped%29.jpg"));
    mockContacts.add(new Contact("Mark Zuckerberg","zuckerberg@gmail.com","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Mark_Zuckerberg_F8_2019_Keynote_%2832830578717%29_%28cropped%29.jpg/220px-Mark_Zuckerberg_F8_2019_Keynote_%2832830578717%29_%28cropped%29.jpg"));
    mockContacts.add(new Contact("Barack Obama","obamabarack@gmail.com","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/220px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg"));
    mockContacts.add(new Contact("Sumire Uesaka","sumipe@gmail.com","https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/voiceactors/1/65562.jpg"));

    //Use adapter class that was created to adapter instance
    ContactsRecViewAdapter adapter =new ContactsRecViewAdapter(this);
    //set mockContacts to adapter
    adapter.setContacts(mockContacts);

    //set adapter to recycle view
    contactsRecView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //configure Recycle view to be vertical list
      contactsRecView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
      }
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
    W/Glide: Load failed for [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Mark_Zuckerberg_F8_2019_Keynote_%2832830578717%29_%28cropped%29.jpg/220px-Mark_Zuckerberg_F8_2019_Keynote_%2832830578717%29_%28cropped%29.jpg] with dimensions [525x525]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:98)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:95)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:88)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:424)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:383)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:93)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:58) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:95) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:88) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:311) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:280) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:235) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:424) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultPriorityThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:383)
```

Comment: can you try adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission as well to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: mind to teach me what is this function? I just deleted emulator and redownload it. the app is working fine now, I am really confused where went wrong.

Comment: @inkredusk please teach me something. Why the old version of android studio, there is something called allprojects{ repositories {}} inside build.gradle, but in my version of android studio those things are there.And once i added them, it output errors on my Run output terminal.